# post 405 method not allowed php forn

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a simple form for a website in HTML and PHP query.

**HTML form**

```
            <form name="contactForm" id="contactForm" method="post" action=""  >
                <fieldset>

                  <div class="group">
                           <input name="contactName" type="text" id="contactName" placeholder="Name" value="" minLength="2" required />
                  </div>
                  <div>
                       <input name="contactEmail" type="email" id="contactEmail" placeholder="Email" value="" required />
                   </div>
                  <div>
                           <input name="contactSubject" type="text" id="contactSubject" placeholder="Subject"  value="" />
                   </div>                       
                  <div>
                        <textarea name="contactMessage"  id="contactMessage" placeholder="message" rows="10" cols="50" required ></textarea>
                   </div>                      
                  <div>
                     <button class="submitform contactdetails1">Submit</button>
                     <div id="submit-loader">
                        <div class="text-loader contactdetails2">Sending...</div>                             
                          <div class="s-loader">
                                    <div class="bounce1"></div>
                                    <div class="bounce2"></div>
                                    <div class="bounce3"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                  </div>
```

After trying to submit the form, I have the error messages that POST 405 NOT ALLOWED. It is unclear from the documentation how to set up a server and fix POST request.

[image]

PHP query

```
<?php

// Replace this with your own email address
$siteOwnersEmail = 'jeremie.xxxxx@xxxxx.com';


if($_POST) {

   $name = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactName']));
   $email = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactEmail']));
   $subject = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactSubject']));
   $contact_message = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactMessage']));

   // Check Name
    if (strlen($name) < 2) {
        $error['name'] = "Please enter your name.";
    }
    // Check Email
    if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9&\'\.\-_\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z0-9\-]+\.)*+[a-z]{2}/is', $email)) {
        $error['email'] = "Please enter a valid email address.";
    }
    // Check Message
    if (strlen($contact_message) < 15) {
        $error['message'] = "Please enter your message. It should have at least 15 characters.";
    }
   // Subject
    if ($subject == '') { $subject = "Contact Form Submission"; }


   // Set Message
   $message .= "Email from: " . $name . "<br />";
    $message .= "Email address: " . $email . "<br />";
   $message .= "Message: <br />";
   $message .= $contact_message;
   $message .= "<br /> ----- <br /> This email was sent from your site's contact form. <br />";

   // Set From: header
   $from =  $name . " <" . $email . ">";

   // Email Headers
    $headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $email . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";


   if (!$error) {

      ini_set("sendmail_from", $siteOwnersEmail); // for windows server
      $mail = mail($siteOwnersEmail, $subject, $message, $headers);

        if ($mail) { echo "OK"; }
      else { echo "Something went wrong. Please try again."; }
        
    } # end if - no validation error

    else {

        $response = (isset($error['name'])) ? $error['name'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
        $response .= (isset($error['email'])) ? $error['email'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
        $response .= (isset($error['message'])) ? $error['message'] . "<br />" : null;
        
        echo $response;

    } # end if - there was a validation error

}

?>
```

...................................................................

Comment: where do u want to post the form? action url is empty.

Comment: Do you have a web server capable of executing PHP scripts running there to begin with? Sounds rather like you actually don't - which is why it thinks your `.php` script file was actually a "static" file, and for those POST requests are usually not alllowed.

Comment: And btw., that you have `/inc/` showing up in paths used on the client side, that kinda defeats the purpose of an _inc(lude)_ file to begin with IMHO.

Comment: It's not clear - what is your questions?

Comment: @Roman, I am looking into web server capable of executing PHP scripts. it is not clear how to set it up..